# While click the layout xml files eclipse get closes?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have got a problem in eclipse that whenever I click the layout xml files to open automatically eclipse get close.I'm doing android application program. Why this happens any idea. Your brilliant idea can help me out.

Thanks in advance 
Bamadeva.

Comment: You get any error log/message before closing? Or you see any error before clicking the xml?

Comment: if you start eclipse from command line/console you might get an error message upon crash. Think it would be helpful to nail down the problem. E.g. for linux `/path/to/your/eclipseInstallation/eclipse` or maybe just `eclipse` might work.

Comment: No,Nothing I get here, It closes directly without any messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running eclipse with the -clean option

```
eclipse -clean
```

You probably have troubles with the android plugin, maybe the designer crashes, maybe installing the plugin again might work...

Comment: Hei Geenux. I tried it still it won't work even I gave the plugins for 2 more times. What need to be done.